# K.function returns "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' "

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I want to calculate the gradients of weights. I am using the following code:

(assume that the *model* is already defined)

(also both data and labels are fed as inputs)

```
weights = model.trainable_weights
gradients = model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss, weights)
input_tensors = [model.input, model.sample_weights, K.learning_phase() ]
getGradients = K.function(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=gradients)
sampleWeights = np.ones(len(image_data))
inputs = [[image_data, labels], sampleWeights, 0 ]
print getGradients(inputs)
```

This, however, returns the following error:
[image]

I am using Keras(v2.0.6) with Tensorflow(v1.2.1) as backend.

Also, is there any other way to do it without using K.function ? (I am new to Keras and Tensorflow).

Comment: Have you tried using a tuple instead of a list?

Comment: @pdowling, this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047044/5635517) actually says that K.function takes lists as input. That is why this error is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake: *model.sample_weights* is a list, which is a problem. Changing it to *model.sample_weights[0]* works.

```
input_tensors = [model.input, model.sample_weights[0], K.learning_phase() ]
```